# Perl - Installing Tk module for Windows

Tags: perl, module, tk-toolkit

I downloaded Tk module and installed it in Perl\lib.

I created the following perl file:

```
use Tk;
use strict;

my $mw = MainWindow->new;
$mw->geometry("200x100");
$mw->title("Frame Test");

$mw->Frame(-background => 'red')->pack(-ipadx => 50, -side => "left", -fill => "y");
$mw->Frame(-background => 'blue')->pack(-ipadx => 50, -side => "right", -fill => "y");

MainLoop;
```

Then, I tried to execute this file by typing "perl filename.pl" in command window, and the result was: "Can't locate Tk.pm in @INC"

Comment: make sure you put it in the right place with `perl -V` will tll you your @INC and how did you install it?

Comment: I just downloaded the folder. I typed "perl -V" and it showed me two paths. I put the folder under on of these two paths and it still didn't work.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what version of Perl are you running?

Answer (score 3):

The Tk module for Perl is an XS module with C code that needs compiling.  Merely copying isn't sufficient.  If you use ActiveState's Perl, you can download/install Tk using `ppm` provided you are either using one of the two most recent version or you are paying for an "enterprise" license.  Otherwise use `cpan` or `cpanm` to do the installation.  You'll also need a C compiler and a copy of nmake.

Comment: I use ActiveState's Perl. How canI use it to download Tk ?

Comment: I have CPAN and I typded the command "cpan TK". I got the following message:



Fetching with LWP:
http://cpan.perl.org/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz
LWP failed with code[500] message[Can't connect to cpan.perl.org:80 (10060)]
Fetching with LWP:
http://cpan.perl.org/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz
LWP failed with code[500] message[Can't connect to cpan.perl.org:80 (10060)]

Fetching with LWP:
http://cpan.perl.org/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz
LWP failed with code[500] message[Can't connect to cpan.perl.org:80 (10060)]

Comment: I downloaded ActivePerl from this address: www.activestate.com/activeperl/downloads

Comment: Those messages look like your interconnection is screwed up.  If you're behind a proxy server you'll have to set some environment variables.  "http_proxy" is, I believe, one of them.  I'll look it up.

Comment: OK, documentation on http_proxy is @ http://docs.activestate.com/activeperl/5.8/faq/ActivePerl-faq2.html

Comment: OK. I solved the problem of proxy server.I typed "cpan Tk" and Tk was downloaded. Still, when I executed this code, I got: 

Can't locate Tk.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Tk module) (@INC contain
s: C:/Perl64/site/lib C:/Perl64/lib .) at file.pl line 1.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at file.pl line 1.

Comment: You've fixed your proxy settings then downloaded, compiled and tested the Tk module in about 20 minutes?  You're *sure* you didn't ignore any error messages in that `cpan` run?

Comment: actually, now I see the following message at the end of cpan run: 

"'windres' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
dmake.exe:  Error code 129, while making 'tkres.o'
dmake.exe:  Error code 255, while making 'pTk\libpTk.a'
  SREZIC/Tk-804.032.tar.gz
  C:\Perl64\site\bin\dmake.exe -- NOT OK"

Comment: I didn't actually solved the proxy problem. I just moved to another computer, in which this problem doesn't exist.